# Скачать изображение

Tags: qt

Имеется ссылка, [типа](https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQr1kdebTEL2Zgj5QJLLx2NKie2CX0GZATxHZYoHWL6ISmEy2rivw). То есть, там содержится одна картинка и ничего больше. Требуется её сохранить. Я смогла это реализовать через `WebEngine`, но надо использовать `QNetworkAccessManager`.

Comment: Посмотрите [этот](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6283701/4924596) ответ

Answer (score 1):

Если разработка идёт под Windows, можно использовать WinApi.

```
#include <urlmon.h>
```

`URLDownloadToFile( 0, "http://www.ya.ru/index.html", "c:\\temp\index.html", 0, 0);`

Если мобильные платформы- используйте этот пример.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-download-main-cpp.html

Comment: Вы так сказали как будто Qt только на мобильных платформах